# Integration multi-threading test to stress test a server

Tags: multithreading, testing, integration, stress-testing

I'm new to the world of C# threads and want to stress test a particular server method.
    I'd like to somehow capture the time taken to run the process and return it in some way. Or, if the server returns an error message, as I ramp up the concurrent threads...
    That is, some sort of decay statistics as the users ramp up. I'm looking for something simple yet effective...
    I'm going to call this process from an integration test like this:

```
[Test]
public void StressTest_SomeExpensiveMethod_Approach()
{

    int NO_THREADS = 10;
    Thread thread = null;
    MyClass myC = new MyClass();

    for (int i = 0; i < NO_THREADS; i++)
    {
        thread = new Thread(myC.DoExpensiveWork);
        thread.Name = i.ToString();
        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        thread.Start(); 
    }
}
```

I have the class `MyClass` below. This class contains the method `DoExpensiveWork()`. I'm trying to call `DoExpensiveWork()` for a specified fixed number of threads (say 10 or 20 and ramp up from there)
SomeExpensiveMethod (an expensive process essentially < 1 second though usually) and then stores the result in  List

I've been told that I need to use callbacks and the locking mechanism but I'm stuck. Can anyone help me please? I'm using parameterised threading but I reckon what I have is wrong.

I need a little bit of coding help here with this one please. I would greatly appreciate if you could modify the example below with your suggestions...

Thanks
Sandra

```
public class MyClass
{   
        public void DoExpensiveWork()
        {

            ServerClass cs = new ServerClass();
            string testData = "sometestdata";

            //*** CALL TO METHOD-UNDER-TEST ***//
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            IList<string> response = cs.SomeExpensiveMethod(testData);
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;        
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have VS 2010 Ultimate or newer, you can create load tests with a bunch of different parameters and the reporting it gives you even while running is very helpful. The link below may help you in your endeavor: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/07/08/load-testing-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx